# Parse data from .xml file and save it to .tsv file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Reviews>
<Review rid="1004293">
    <sentences>
        <sentence id="1004293:0">
            <text>Judging from previous posts this used to be a good place, but not any longer.</text>
            <Opinions>
                <Opinion target="place" category="RESTAURANT#GENERAL" polarity="negative" from="51" to="56"/>
            </Opinions>
        </sentence>
        <sentence id="1004293:1">
            <text>The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.</text>
            <Opinions>
                <Opinion target="food" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="4" to="8"/>
                <Opinion target="NULL" category="SERVICE#GENERAL" polarity="negative" from="0" to="0"/>
            </Opinions>
        </sentence>
...
```

How can I parse the data from this .xml file to .tsv file in the following format:

["negative", "Judging from previous posts this used to be a good place, but not any longer.", "RESTAURANT#GENERAL"]

["positive", "The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.","FOOD#QUALITY"]

["negative", "The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.","SERVICE#GENERAL"]

Thanks!

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we do expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done that and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we can try to assist. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use elementtree package of python to get your desired output. Below is the code which will print your list. You can create a tsv by replacing the print and writing to a tsv file.

The sample.xml file must be present in the same directory where this code is present.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

file = 'sample.xml'

tree = ElementTree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for sentence in root.iter('sentence'):
# Loop all sentence in the xml
    for opinion in sentence.iter('Opinion'):
    # Loop all Opinion of a particular sentence.
        print([opinion.attrib['polarity'], sentence.find('text').text, opinion.attrib['category']])
```

Output:

```
['negative', 'Judging from previous posts this used to be a good place, but not any longer.', 'RESTAURANT#GENERAL']                                                     
['positive', 'The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.', 'FOOD#QUALITY']                                                                      
['negative', 'The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.', 'SERVICE#GENERAL']
```

sample.xml contains:

```
<Reviews>
<Review rid="1004293">
    <sentences>
        <sentence id="1004293:0">
            <text>Judging from previous posts this used to be a good place, but not any longer.</text>
            <Opinions>
                <Opinion target="place" category="RESTAURANT#GENERAL" polarity="negative" from="51" to="56"/>
            </Opinions>
        </sentence>
        <sentence id="1004293:1">
            <text>The food here is rather good, but only if you like to wait for it.</text>
            <Opinions>
                <Opinion target="food" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="4" to="8"/>
                <Opinion target="NULL" category="SERVICE#GENERAL" polarity="negative" from="0" to="0"/>
            </Opinions>
        </sentence>
    </sentences>
</Review>
```